# IONIC 4 ion-menu not showing on ion-menu-button click

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to add a side menu using ion-menu in Angular 6 app, but when I add the button for toggling the menu, and click it, nothing happens. No errors or anything.

// where root ion-app is

```
<ion-app>  
  <ion-menu side="start" contentId="content" menuId="1">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
      Menu
    </ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
    <ion-menu-toggle>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Menu item 1</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>

  <ion-router-outlet id="content" main></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>

// and the button in a different file from where we open the menu
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-menu-button menu="1" autoHide="false"></ion-menu-button>
  </ion-buttons>
```

This should be all required to show/hide the menu according to the ionic 4 docs.

Comment: Can you share the link for that documentation?

Answer (score 3):

no need to recreate or start from scratch your app, I had the same issue just yesterday and after struggling for hours and browsing the docs I managed to get it working as expected, this is my code in case is of any use for you

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-split-pane contentId="main-content">
    <ion-menu side="start" contentId="main-content" type="overlay">
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <button ion-button menuToggle icon-only color="dark">
              <ion-icon name='close'></ion-icon>
            </button>
            <ion-title></ion-title>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content>
          <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
              <p class="ion-text-center">
                <ion-thumbnail item-center>
                  <img [src]="userImgProfile" class="menu-picture--profile" style="border-radius: 50%; margin: auto; display: block;">
                </ion-thumbnail>
              </p>
              <p class="ion-text-center">
                {{ usrName }}
              </p>
            </ion-item>
            <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
              <ion-item (click)="support()">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="help-buoy"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>
                  Soporte
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-menu-toggle>
            <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false">
              <ion-item (click)="logout()">
                <ion-icon slot="start" name="power"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>
                  Cerrar sesion
                </ion-label>
              </ion-item>
            </ion-menu-toggle>
          </ion-list>
        </ion-content>

    </ion-menu>
    <ion-router-outlet id="main-content" main></ion-router-outlet>
  </ion-split-pane>
</ion-app>
```

and on the inner pages, this is the header I'm using

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar hideBackButton="true">
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>
      <span>
        Tus Negocios
      </span>
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="support()" color="dark" style="color: #ff4500;">
        <ion-icon name='chatboxes'></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to add a sidemenu manually. If that is true, you need not do that manually. While creating the project, add the type of project you want to create. Use the keywords like `blank`, `sidemenu`, `tabs`.
The command goes like this `ionic start myApp sidemenu`. This will create the project with sidemenu and you need not do it manually.

Hope this helps.